# Update on has_many should update attribute on the parent class

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a `User` model which `has_many :scores`.

If I add a :score to the user, the user should do a recalculation of the playcounter:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :scores, inverse_of: :user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :scores

  attr_accessible :level

  before_save: set_levels

  def set_levels
    self.level = calculate_level
  end

  def calculate_level
    self.scores.count
  end

end
```

When I add a score via `User.score.create(:time => 10)` the score get's saved but the level does not get updated.

How can I rerun the `set_levels` if a child was attached?

(it's not a countercache column, method it's more complex, just sketched here)

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a callback to the `Score` model, perhaps an `after_commit` on the score model to tell the parent `User` to recalculate the level.

```
class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit do
    # can just call touch, as before_save will calc
    user.touch
  end
end
```

Now, that is only if you want to recalculate on every score, and synchronously.
More often I will drop a message, such as to resque/sidekiq, to do this, so my score create/updates are fast.

```
class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit do
    UpdateUserLevelWorker.perform_async(user_id)
  end
end

class UpdateUserLevelWorker

  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(user_id)
    # can just call touch, as before_save will calc
    User.find(user_id).touch
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for your reply. I got another approach which solved my prob.

Comment: I don't think your solution will work if you create the score directly - i.e. Score.create(user_id:1, value:123), as it won't update the parent, and trigger your user level update.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working with

```
after_create :set_level

def set_level
  self.update_attribute :level, calculate_level
end
```